# Deserializing a DateTime from a string millisecond timestamp with serde

Tags: rust, serde, rust-chrono

I receive a millisecond timestamp from an external API as a JSON string attribute.

```
{"time":"1526522699918"}
```

Whats the best way to use Serde to parse the millisecond timestamp as a string?

The `ts_milliseconds` option works with a millisecond timestamp as an integer, but throws an error when using a string.

Example - [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f4e0bb8adec9788cb9a02bddfa3de689)

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::serde::ts_milliseconds;
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct S {
    #[serde(with = "ts_milliseconds")]
    time: DateTime<Utc>,
}

fn main() {
    serde_json::from_str::<S>(r#"{"time":1526522699918}"#).unwrap(); // millisecond timestamp as a integer
    serde_json::from_str::<S>(r#"{"time":"1526522699918"}"#).unwrap(); // millisecond timestamp as an string
}
```

Error message:

```
Error("invalid type: string \"1526522699918\", expected a unix timestamp in milliseconds", line: 1, column: 23)'
```

Comment: see https://serde.rs/string-or-struct.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Abstracting over the serialized for of `DateTime` is possible using the `TimestampMilliSeconds` type from `serde_with`.
With it, you can serialize to / deserialize from floats, integers, or strings. You need to enable the `chrono` feature for `serde_with`.

The first argument (here `String`) configures the serialization behavior. In case of `String` this means the `DateTime` will be serialized as a string containing a Unix timestamp in milliseconds.

The second argument (here `Flexible`) allows configuring the deserialization behavior. `Flexible` means that it will deserialize from floats, integers, and strings without returning an error. You can use that to get the `main` function from the question to run. The other option is `Strict`, which only deserializes the format from the first argument. For this example this means it would only deserialize the time as a string, but would return an error when encountering the integer.

```rust
use ::chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use serde_with::TimestampMilliSeconds;
use serde_with::formats::Flexible;

#[serde_with::serde_as]
#[derive(serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize)]
struct S {
    #[serde_as(as = "TimestampMilliSeconds<String, Flexible>")]
    time: DateTime<Utc>,
}

fn main() {
    serde_json::from_str::<S>(r#"{"time":1526522699918}"#).unwrap(); // millisecond timestamp as a integer
    serde_json::from_str::<S>(r#"{"time":"1526522699918"}"#).unwrap(); // millisecond timestamp as an string
}
```